# Fine Tuning GPT-3 for Consistent Output Format

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to use Open AI API to create quiz questions with three incorrect answers and one correct answer. The prompt I use is

```
`Write a quiz on ${quiz_topic} with 5 questions. Each question has 3 incorrect answers and 1 correct answer. The correct answer is always the last answer. Write each answer on a separate line`
```

I would like to parse ChatGPT's answer but the format is inconsistent. For instance, is quiz_topic is "literature", I get the following response:

```
Q1. Who wrote the novel "The Catcher in the Rye"?

A. J.D. Salinger
B. Ernest Hemingway
C. F. Scott Fitzgerald
D. Mark Twain
```

This is the correct format. But if I use "U.S History", I get the following output:

```
Q1: Who was the first president of the United States?

A1: George Washington Jr., Thomas Jefferson, John Adams, George Washington
```

This is a different format. So my goal is to fine-tune it using the article [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning)

I have created 200 line of a training set. Here is a sample:

```
{"prompt":"Write a quiz on general knowledge with 5 questions. Each question has 3 incorrect answers and 1 correct answer. The correct answer is always the last answer.Write each answer on a separate line \n\n---\n\n","completion":" Q. What is the Italian word for &quot;tomato&quot;?\nA. Aglio\nA. Cipolla\nA. Peperoncino\nA. Pomodoro\n\nQ. Which restaurant&#039;s mascot is a clown?\nA. Whataburger\nA. Burger King\nA. Sonic\nA. McDonald&#039;s\n\nQ. Which of these colours is NOT featured in the logo for Google?\nA. Yellow\nA. Blue\nA. Green\nA. Pink\n\nQ. In 2013 how much money was lost by Nigerian scams?\nA. $95 Million\nA. $956 Million\nA. $2.7 Billion\nA. $12.7 Billion\n\nQ. What is the name of Poland in Polish?\nA. Pupcia\nA. Polszka\nA. P&oacute;land\nA. Polska\n\n \n\n###\n\n"}
{"prompt":"Write a quiz on books with 5 questions. Each question has 3 incorrect answers and 1 correct answer. The correct answer is always the last answer.Write each answer on a separate line \n\n---\n\n","completion":" Q. What is the name of Eragon&#039;s dragon in &quot;Eragon&quot;?\nA. Glaedr\nA. Thorn\nA. Arya\nA. Saphira\n\nQ. In the &quot;The Hobbit&quot;, who kills Smaug?\nA. Bilbo Baggins\nA. Gandalf the Grey\nA. Frodo\nA. Bard\n\nQ. What is Hermione Granger&#039;s middle name?\nA. Jane\nA. Emma\nA. Jo\nA. Jean\n\nQ. According to The Hitchhiker&#039;s Guide to the Galaxy book, the answer to life, the universe and everything else is...\nA. Loving everyone around you\nA. Chocolate\nA. Death\nA. 42\n\nQ. What is the name of the three headed dog in Harry Potter and the Sorcerer&#039;s Stone?\nA. Spike\nA. Poofy\nA. Spot\nA. Fluffy\n\n \n\n###\n\n"}
```

When I run the validation tool with the command

```
openai tools fine_tunes.prepare_data -f training.jsonl
```

I get the following message

```
- All prompts start with prefix `Write a quiz on `. Fine-tuning doesn't require the instruction specifying the task, or a few-shot example scenario. Most of the time you should only add the input data into the prompt, and the desired output into the completion
```

I don't understand why I must remove "Write a quiz on". So I have misunderstood how to fine-tune a model for consistent formatting.
Can anybody shed a light on how to make sure I get the same formatting with the same prompt

Answer (score 2):

Reading the fine-tuning page on the OpenAI website, I understood that after the fine-tuning you will not have the necessity to specify the task, it will intuit the task. This saves your tokens removing "Write a quiz on" from the promt.

> GPT-3 has been pre-trained on a vast amount of text from the open internet. When given a prompt with just a few examples, it can often intuit what task you are trying to perform and generate a plausible completion. This is often called "few-shot learning."
> Fine-tuning improves on few-shot learning by training on many more examples than can fit in the prompt, letting you achieve better results on a wide number of tasks. Once a model has been fine-tuned, you won't need to provide examples in the prompt anymore. This saves costs and enables lower-latency requests.

Answer (score 0):

Writing prompts for fine-tuning is different than writing prompts for ChatGPT. Instead of providing all the instructions up front, your goal is to provide enough examples so that the model can recognize the pattern on its own.

Your training data should be formatted more like this:

**Prompt**

```
Topic: Literature
Number of answers: 4
```

**Completion**

```
Who wrote the novel "The Catcher in the Rye"?

A. J.D. Salinger
B. Ernest Hemingway
C. F. Scott Fitzgerald
D. Mark Twain (correct)
```

I would include that `(correct)` label in the formatting of your answers initially, since it will reduce the number of examples that your model needs until it can "get the hang" of it.

Once you build up your training set to a larger number, you can try removing it and see if the model still recognizes the pattern of truthfulness in the answers, as well as the desired order where the correct one is at the end, and performs accurately.

Changes like that are much easier if you use a tool like [Entry Point](https://www.entrypointai.com) to define your fields and write the prompt/completion templates.